# Chartkick workds locally, but on Heroku "no adaptor found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, chartkick

I'm using Chartkick in Rails to generate charts through Google's API. It works fine on my development system, but live on Heroku Chartkick gives this error message:

```
Error Loading Chart: No adapter found
```

In `app/views/layouts/application.rb` I have this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
```

I've tried turning on the assets pipeline in `config/application.rb` with `config.serve_static_assets = true` and I've tried downloading Google's `jsapi.js` and putting it under `vendor/assets/javascript`

but these aren't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked it out. I needed this in application.js

```
//= require jsapi
//= require chartkick
```

I don't know why it worked on localhost, but not Heroku. But now that has fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

If it is in `vendor`, you need to require it in production.
    In `application.js:`

```
//= require jsapi
```

When you go to production, the asset pipeline gathers everything required and puts it in a massive .js file in public/assets